# Chart.js not displaying in box

Tags: php, jquery, chart.js

i'm making a website to connect to a database and displaying the data with a graph using Chart.js but for some reason it's not working and i cant figure out why. My entire php file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
This is a starter template page. Use this page to start your new project from
scratch. This page gets rid of all links and provides the needed markup only.
-->
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>AdminLTE 2 | Starter</title>
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
  <!-- AdminLTE Skins. We have chosen the skin-blue for this starter
        page. However, you can choose any other skin. Make sure you
        apply the skin class to the body tag so the changes take effect.
  -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/skins/skin-blue.min.css">

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
<!--
javascript code 
-->
</head>
<!--
BODY TAG OPTIONS:
=================
Apply one or more of the following classes to get the
desired effect
|---------------------------------------------------------|
| SKINS         | skin-blue                               |
|               | skin-black                              |
|               | skin-purple                             |
|               | skin-yellow                             |
|               | skin-red                                |
|               | skin-green                              |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
|LAYOUT OPTIONS | fixed                                   |
|               | layout-boxed                            |
|               | layout-top-nav                          |
|               | sidebar-collapse                        |
|               | sidebar-mini                            |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
-->
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">

<div class="wrapper">

  <!-- Main Header -->
  <header class="main-header">


    <!-- Header Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
      <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
      <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      </a>
      <!-- Navbar Right Menu -->
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
  <aside class="main-sidebar">

    <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
    <section class="sidebar">

      <!-- search form (Optional) -->
      <form action="#" method="get" class="sidebar-form">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="submit" onclick="search_button()" name="search" id="search-btn" class="btn btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>
              </span>
        </div>
      </form>
      <!-- /.search form -->

      <!-- Sidebar Menu -->

      <!-- /.sidebar-menu -->
    </section>
    <!-- /.sidebar -->
  </aside>

  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <h1>
        Greenhouse information
        <small>Select a greenhouse for more info</small>
      </h1>
    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content" id="maincontent">

<!-- LINE CHART -->         
    <div class="box box-info" style="height:400px">
        <div class="box-header with-border">
            <h3 class="box-title">Line Chart</h3>
        </div>
          <div class="box-body" style="height:400px">
            <div class="chart" style="height:400px">
              <canvas id="lineChart" style="height:400px"></canvas>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.box-body -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.box -->

    <!-- Your Page Content Here -->

    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->

  <!-- Main Footer -->
  <footer class="main-footer">
    <!-- To the right -->
    <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
      Anything you want
    </div>
    <!-- Default to the left -->
    <strong>Copyright &copy; 2015 <a href="#">Company</a>.</strong> All rights reserved.
  </footer>

  <!-- Control Sidebar -->
  <aside class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark">
    <!-- Create the tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified control-sidebar-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a href="#control-sidebar-home-tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#control-sidebar-settings-tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-gears"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
      <!-- Home tab content -->
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="control-sidebar-home-tab">
        <h3 class="control-sidebar-heading">Recent Activity</h3>
        <ul class="control-sidebar-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="javascript::;">
              <i class="menu-icon fa fa-birthday-cake bg-red"></i>

              <div class="menu-info">
                <h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading">Langdon's Birthday</h4>

                <p>Will be 23 on April 24th</p>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- /.control-sidebar-menu -->

        <h3 class="control-sidebar-heading">Tasks Progress</h3>
        <ul class="control-sidebar-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="javascript::;">
              <h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading">
                Custom Template Design
                <span class="label label-danger pull-right">70%</span>
              </h4>

              <div class="progress progress-xxs">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: 70%"></div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- /.control-sidebar-menu -->

      </div>
      <!-- /.tab-pane -->
      <!-- Stats tab content -->
      <div class="tab-pane" id="control-sidebar-stats-tab">Stats Tab Content</div>
      <!-- /.tab-pane -->
      <!-- Settings tab content -->
      <div class="tab-pane" id="control-sidebar-settings-tab">
        <form method="post">
          <h3 class="control-sidebar-heading">General Settings</h3>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-sidebar-subheading">
              Report panel usage
              <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right" checked>
            </label>

            <p>
              Some information about this general settings option
            </p>
          </div>
          <!-- /.form-group -->
        </form>
      </div>
      <!-- /.tab-pane -->
    </div>
  </aside>
  <!-- /.control-sidebar -->
  <!-- Add the sidebar's background. This div must be placed
       immediately after the control sidebar -->
  <div class="control-sidebar-bg"></div>
</div>
<!-- ./wrapper -->

<!-- REQUIRED JS SCRIPTS -->

<!-- jQuery 2.1.4 -->
<script src="plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
<!-- ChartJS 1.0.1 -->
<!-- <script src="../../plugins/chartjs/Chart.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="../../Chart.js-master/Chart.min.js"></script>

<!-- FastClick -->
<script src="../../plugins/fastclick/fastclick.min.js"></script>


<!-- Optionally, you can add Slimscroll and FastClick plugins.
     Both of these plugins are recommended to enhance the
     user experience. Slimscroll is required when using the
     fixed layout. -->

<!--
PHP code for database
-->

<script>
  $(function () {
    var areaChartData = {
      labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "Electronics",
          fillColor: "rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)",
          strokeColor: "rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)",
          pointColor: "rgba(210, 214, 222, 1)",
          pointStrokeColor: "#c1c7d1",
          pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
          pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
          data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        },
        {
          label: "Digital Goods",
          fillColor: "rgba(60,141,188,0.9)",
          strokeColor: "rgba(60,141,188,0.8)",
          pointColor: "#3b8bba",
          pointStrokeColor: "rgba(60,141,188,1)",
          pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
          pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(60,141,188,1)",
          data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
        }
      ]
    };

    var areaChartOptions = {
      //Boolean - If we should show the scale at all
      showScale: true,
      //Boolean - Whether grid lines are shown across the chart
      scaleShowGridLines: false,
      //String - Colour of the grid lines
      scaleGridLineColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.05)",
      //Number - Width of the grid lines
      scaleGridLineWidth: 1,
      //Boolean - Whether to show horizontal lines (except X axis)
      scaleShowHorizontalLines: true,
      //Boolean - Whether to show vertical lines (except Y axis)
      scaleShowVerticalLines: true,
      //Boolean - Whether the line is curved between points
      bezierCurve: true,
      //Number - Tension of the bezier curve between points
      bezierCurveTension: 0.3,
      //Boolean - Whether to show a dot for each point
      pointDot: false,
      //Number - Radius of each point dot in pixels
      pointDotRadius: 4,
      //Number - Pixel width of point dot stroke
      pointDotStrokeWidth: 1,
      //Number - amount extra to add to the radius to cater for hit detection outside the drawn point
      pointHitDetectionRadius: 20,
      //Boolean - Whether to show a stroke for datasets
      datasetStroke: true,
      //Number - Pixel width of dataset stroke
      datasetStrokeWidth: 2,
      //Boolean - Whether to fill the dataset with a color
      datasetFill: false,
      //String - A legend template
      legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\"><% for (var i=0; i<datasets.length; i++){%><li><span style=\"background-color:<%=datasets[i].lineColor%>\"></span><%if(datasets[i].label){%><%=datasets[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>",
      //Boolean - whether to maintain the starting aspect ratio or not when responsive, if set to false, will take up entire container
      maintainAspectRatio: true,
      //Boolean - whether to make the chart responsive to window resizing
      responsive: true
    };
    //-------------
    //- LINE CHART -
    //--------------
    var lineChartOptions = areaChartOptions;
    var lineChartCanvas = $("#lineChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
    var lineChart = new Chart(lineChartCanvas).line(areaChartData,lineChartOptions);
  });
</script>
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$database = "simsdatabase";
$username = "test";
$password = "sims";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";

$getinfo = "SELECT Name FROM greenhouse";
$names = $conn->query($getinfo);
$result = $names->fetch_assoc();
echo $result["Name"];
?> 
</body>
</html>
```

and no mater what i've tried i cant figure out how to make the graph show in the Canvas with ID Linechart, can anyone see what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: I think you should be seeing an error with the above code. The method is `Line` (with a capital L)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Changing the L gave me an error message to work with and i managed to figure it out :) After i changed the L i got the error: ReferenceError: Chart is not defined. From there i looked at the <script src="../../Chart.js-master/Chart.min.js"></script> and removed the ../../ part and now it works like a dream!

Answer (score 0):

Potatopeelings sugested i change the L in

```
var lineChart = new Chart(lineChartCanvas).line(areaChartData,lineChartOptions);
```

and that gave me an error message: ReferenceError: Chart is not defined. With that I managed to find the problem. When i included the Char.js i used

```
<script src="../../Chart.js-master/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

but it started working once i removed the ../../ in the begining of the file path.
Thanks for the help Potatopeelings :)